# Re-stream/Mirror HTTP Live Stream

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I need to re-stream/mirror some HLS’s (HTTP Live Stream) using a Linux server.

From input

```
http://anystream.com/channel1.m3u8
```

To output

```
http://127.0.0.1/abc.m3u8
```

I found several media servers but they lack of documentation. (like crtmpserver or next gen media server)
But it doesn’t have to be a server solution, a how-to for ffmpeg or a PHP/Phyton script (if possible) would be great too.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `ffmpeg` - it does have `ffserver` which allows to either prepare a local file for on-demand streaming, or you could also set the stream address as a source and re-broadcast it via `ffserver` - I did a few tests a couple of years ago - including mplayer, which I used to get the stream, re-encode via `ffmpeg` and push it to `ffserver`

My idea of "rebroadcast" was to provide a local, stream server on LAN, and have the clients connect locally, instead opening 10-20 connections to the remote and killing the WAN.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easlily with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/). Just stream the link using the GUI, and as soon as you could be able to do this, you can extract the command line and run it as command line on your server. Result will be something like this:

```
vlc http://anystream.com/channel1.m3u8 :sout=#http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/music} :sout-keep
```

But, be sure to use GUI and replace the streaming code yourself to get it easy.